# Linux + exit status from Perl one-liner code

Tags: linux, perl, ksh

I use Perl one-liners in my ksh scripts.

Sometimes it's necessary to get an exit status from the Perl one-liner in order to verify if the Perl one-liner succeeded or not.

For example, I need to verify if the "print" in the Perl one-liner code succeeded or not.

But Perl will exit with status 0 in both cases even if Perl does not match the words "AAA and BBB".

Maybe by changing my code I can get **exit status 0** when Perl matches successfully. And get **exit status 1** when Perl does not match the words "AAA and BBB".

Is this possible?

```
more file
AAA BBB


perl -ne '/AAA/ && /BBB/ && print' file
AAA BBB

echo $?
0
```

```
more file1
ZZZ

perl -ne '/AAA/ && /BBB/ && print' file1
echo $?
 0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Count matching lines and set exit code based on it in an `END{...}` block:

```
perl -ne '/AAA/ && /BBB/ && print && $MATCH++; END{exit 1 unless $MATCH>0}' file
```

Comment: another question - where to put the "&& $MATCH++; END{exit 1 unless $MATCH>0}'" on ---> perl -ne'BEGIN { $ip = shift(@ARGV); } print if /(^|\s)\Q$ip\E(\s|$)/; ' "$STR" file

Comment: perl -ne 'BEGIN{ ... }; if( .... ) { print; $MATCH++ }; END{ exit 1 unless $MATCH>0 };'

Comment: I got error: perl -ne'BEGIN { $ip = shift(@ARGV); }; if (^|\s)\Q$ip\E(\s|$) { print; $MATCH++ }; END{ exit 1 unless $MATCH>0 };' "$STR" file
syntax error at -e line 1, near "(^"
Substitution replacement not terminated at -e line 1.^C

Comment: fix `if` statement between BEGIN and END blocks:  `if( /(^|\s)\Q$ip\E(\s|$)/ ) { print; $MATCH++};`